# NullPointerException in rest webservice upload

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am trying to upload a file using a rest webservice. This is my code

```
@Path(value= "/up")
public class upload {

    @POST
    @Path(value="upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream ) {
        String filePath = "C://Users/Marya/Desktop/file" ;
        System.out.println("*****serverpath********");
        saveFile(fileInputStream, filePath); //this is line 29 
        System.out.println("*****save********");
        String output = "File saved to  server location : " + filePath;
        System.out.println("done");
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }

    private void saveFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,String serverLocation) {
        try {OutputStream outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(serverLocation));
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(serverLocation));
            while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) //this is lione 42
            {
                outpuStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
                System.out.println("*****read********");
            }
            outpuStream.flush();
            outpuStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it, the file is created but it is empty with size = 0 !! 
and I get this error:

```
Grave: "Servlet.service()" pour la servlet JAX-RS Servlet a généré une exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.upload.saveFile(upload.java:42)
at com.example.upload.uploadFile(upload.java:29)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
```

Are there any suggestions please to solve this issue ??

Comment: Looks like `fileInputStream` is null.

Comment: [Here](http://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/) you have an example how you can do that.

Comment: Yes this is the problem @Jens . The example in the link It is not what I need in my case

Comment: How does your HTTP request look like? I would like to see how do you upload the file.

Comment: I am using the Google Application ( REST Console) to run this webservice And I add the fileInputStream as attachement